# Using another GameComponent to measure the elapsed times

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Okay, so I started developing a game. The first thing I wanted to set up was an extensive Debug viewer, which can ultimately show things like buttons pressed (only those that I want to listen to of course) and a graph containing information about frametime, a histogram of sorts. However, I wanted to do this the *correct* way. It occurred to me that I wanted to use the DrawableGameComponent class for the debugviewer, and draw the debug information there. However it seems that it can't measure the Update and Draw times correctly, as I start the update timer at the beginning of the update and end the update at the beginning of the draw. However, I shortly thereafter realized that first the main game is executed (update - draw - wait) and then are all the other components executed (update component 1, draw component 1), so they aren't intertwined. This means that I can't calculate the elapsedtime (for both Update, Draw and overhead). As we can read in [this blog](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/fps_versus_frame_time.htm) it's better to measure frametime as opposed to frames per seconds.

So enough with the back story and on to my main question: How do I measure the frametimes needed for both the Update, the Draw and the overhead from the main game in another DrawableGameComponent, or should I just use a class and update that in the game?

I hope that everything is clear, have a great day.

Comment: Have you considered simply using a commercial (some are free) profiler that probably has many extra features that you may find useful but never get around to implementing/coding on your own?

Comment: That is because I enjoy to program and find solutions for myself, however this problem had me questioning for a couple of hours, and I didn't know how to do it. Basically, I don't want to rely on other's for my own project, even though I rely on XNA, but it's no longer supported... Anyhow, perhaps I can look up on those profilers to see what they offer so I can copy that idea and implement it myself.

Answer (score 0):

i found this http://gamedevwithoutacause.com/?p=876 which explaines exactly what you need.

Comment: I have indeed found that post, however this is added to the game1 class. I wanted it in another "DrawableGameComponent" so that the DebugView (drawablegamecomponent) handles everything debuggy (frametime, controlls, histograms etc.). I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't measure the `Update` and `Draw` times correctly, using the update timer, can't you simply use `DateTime.Now`? You get it at the beginning of your `Update`, then every next cycle (after `Update`, `Draw` and overhead) you just subtract the `DateTime.Now` measured previously.

Comment: I suppose that'd work, however I wanted more information than that. I want to know how long an update cycle takes, and a draw cycle. This is relatively usefull for debugging, so that I can pinpoint where the lag might be, So that I don't have to check both the Update and the Draw cycles.  I have the solution just know, making another 'GameManagement' class, which my new game inherits from, which shall contain the frametime measure and passing that to the DebugView.

Comment: I don't think that the Draw cycle affects really much the game performance (so you don't need to care about it), the most of the time is always spent in the Update cycle. Anyway, if you've already found the solution, never mind.

Comment: Well, the Draw cycle does can affect the overall performance. When, for example, you have one object, a cube, and draw it. When you get 900 FPS, and when you add another cube you suddenly get 450 FPS. This could mean that the update cycle is wrong, or, more logically, the draw cycle is wrong (you start the spritebatch for each cube). To debug this you'd need to know the update, draw and maybe the GPU (or overhead) for everything. That's why it's better to measure performance for update, draw and overhead.